# CSS nth-of-type not updating after JS removal of class

Tags: javascript, css

I've created this JSFiddle of the below: http://jsfiddle.net/qTLmV/

Here is the CSS I'm using:

```
.nested > .addable-group > div.active:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: blue;
}

.nested > .addable-group > div.active:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: grey;
}
```

The simplified layout:

```
<div class="nested">
  <div class="addable-group">
    <div class="active"><a href="#">remove 1</a></div>
    <div class="active"><a href="#">remove 2</a></div>
    <div class="active"><a href="#">remove 3</a></div>
    <div class="active"><a href="#">remove 4</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The JS

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(event) {
  var container = $(this).parent();
  container.hide();
  container.removeClass("active");
  //container.remove();
  return event.preventDefault();
});
```

What I'm trying to do is, if any of the "remove" links are clicked they should get hidden, have their "active" class removed and the alternating background colors should stay consistent. However, I haven't been able to get this working. If I remove the DOM element completely it works, but simply removing the class does not.

I don't want to remove the DOM elements completely because in the live app they contain form fields that, when submitted, remove the record for that element from the DB.

Is there something I'm missing?

EDIT: As a quick and dirty solution I ended up just moving the "removed" items to the bottom of the group: http://jsfiddle.net/qTLmV/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:nth-of-type()` doesn't look at the class, it only looks at the element type. All the children of `.addable-group` are `div` elements, and whether you have the `.active` class or not on one of them doesn't change the fact that it's the nth `div` child of `.addable-group`.

If you need to style these elements according to the `.active` class only, I'm afraid you will need to apply a different class using JS and style by that class instead.

Comment: It was more that I wanted the alternating background color to be easily handled instead of adding/removing classes with JS to get the colors accurate.

Comment: Are there any other selectors or methods of doing this purely with CSS or am I relegated to a JS solution?

Comment: @greetification: You may be out of luck then, as that's quite simply not how the `:nth-of-type()` selector works. There is no other pure CSS solution that I know of (unless you're willing to try using a gradient, but I don't have much experience with those).

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(event) {
    var container = $(this).parent();
    $(this).remove();
    container.remove();    
});
```

Comment: Yes, that will work but I don't want to remove the DOM element completely because in the live app it contains form objects that need to be processed for removal.